# Apple ID: How to avoid changing password?

Tags: icloud, apple-id, password

Whenever I try to log in to iCloud or https://appleid.apple.com/ from my PC I am getting forced to change my password ...

[image]

I do not want to change it. Is there any way to stop these messages?

Comment: I've edited your question down to one question only. You can always ask the other question seperatly.

Answer (score 1):

This message is part of the security measures of iCloud. The only way to get rid of it is to actually set a new password adhering to the rules listed.

Comment: <rant> I've always hated that password policy. Some passwords that are simple to enter on a keyboard are an absolute 'mare on a phone. I'd rather type 16 letters than have to flip between upper/lower/numbers just to type 8 on a phone keyboard </rant>

Comment: @Tetsujin I can relate. Took me a while to find a passwort patterns which reduces the number of flips...

Comment: “MeId10T” works :)